# Using jasypt-spring-boot when deploying to Apache Tomcat

Tags: spring, jasypt

I'm trying to use the [jasypt-spring-boot](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot) and deploy it to a Tomcat server as war.
How to pass the encryptor password, in this case, to ensure the encrypted values could be read?
All the provided example are about running a `jar` file or a Spring Boot app as  follows:

```
java -Djasypt.encryptor.password={my-password-to-decrypt} -jar target/jasypt-spring-boot-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

May be add some settings to `catalina.properties` file in the Tomcat `conf` folder as we do for example when defining active profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to achieve that:

- create a `setenv.sh` file in CATALINE_HOME/bin folder
- add the following entry to set the environment variable on the Tomcat startup:

```
export JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD=your-password
```

- save and restart Tomcat.